# setar um campo model django através de um método

Tags: python, django

fala pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou modelando dois obj em django:

1. Cria uma solicitacao de serviço
2. Recebe esta solicitação e cria uma Ordem de serviço

Ao ser criada uma Ordem de Serviço, que é uma ForeignKey de Solicitação, eu gostaria de setar o campo 'is_active' da solicitação.

Porém não estou conseguindo pensar em uma maneira correta de se fazer isto.

```
class SolicitacaoServico(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    solicitante = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    maquina = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.maquina

class OrdemServico(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    solicitacao = models.ForeignKey(SolicitacaoServico, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_abertura = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    previsao_fechamento = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
```

Consigo fazer isto através de algum método?

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código do views.py?

Comment: O relacionamento de `SolicitacaoServico` e `OrdemServico` é 1 pra 1? O que deveria acontecer se o usuário possui 2 ordens de serviço para uma mesma solicitação?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso através de signals. Nesse caso o metódo post-save. Segue a documentação: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/

Seria mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def set_is_active_service_request(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
     if created:
        solicitacao = instance.solicitacao
        solicitacao.is_active = True
        solicitacao.save()

post_save.connect(set_is_active_service_request, sender=OrdemServico)
```

Esclarecendo, após a ordem de serviço ser criada o método save é executado, após o save (post-save) a função set_is_active_service_request é chamada setando o valor de is_active da solicitação. Ps: O padrão atual é implementar esse método ao fim do arquivo models.py

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).